# HTML Login Form for PHPMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, forms, whmcs

I am currently writing a php module for our billing software that will allow us to easily create/terminate/etc. databases for our customers as a free service. The module template supports the creation of quick login buttons and the example code uses an HTML form to post the data.

Can PHPMyAdmin be logged into in this manner? Haven't found much from Google searches yet pertaining to this.

```
function module_AdminLink($params)
{
    $code = '<form action=\"http://'.$params["serverip"].'/controlpanel" method="post" target="_blank">
<input type="hidden" name="user" value="'.$params["serverusername"].'" />
<input type="hidden" name="pass" value="'.$params["serverpassword"].'" />
<input type="submit" value="PHPMyAdmin" />
</form>';
    return $code;
}
```

Comment: look at the form, that is used to login from the phpmyadmin site. if method, action and username/password-fields match it should work

Comment: There seems to be hidden fields with randomly generated values such as <input type="hidden" name="phpMyAdmin" value="digm73scotbas9il3t8abfb6n8fss9jk" /> will I need all of these or only the method/action/user/pass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i can't comment yet, but phpmyadmin login form needs a session token...
you may [download the software](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/downloads.php) and search in php code how to create that token

Comment: Yes, these will be the hidden fields. The session ID sits on the end of URLs so he would need this. Good answer +1